# Google Docs Script: Move cell to two other sheets onEdit but no duplicates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I know Google Sheet formulas pretty well but not scripting.

I borrowed someone elses code from stack overflow, tinkered, and failed misserably.

Basically, what I am trying to do is when I type text into a cell in column A in 1 sheet, i want it to move that text to the next available, or (+1 from the last row) in two other sheets, both column As. I also need it to check for duplicates and not add the text to that sheet at all if the text exactly matches another cell.

Here is the code I have been tinkering with.

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "AddMember" && r.getColumn() == 27 && r.getValue() == "y") {

var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("InputVPData");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

var targetSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("InputSoulData");
var target = targetSheet2.getRange(targetSheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row); 
}
}
```

This script sometimes moves my cell to both sheets, sometimes it adds it to just one sheet, sometimes it adds the cell twice to the same sheet, and sometimes it just deletes my original cell and doesn't do anything with it.

Additionally, I don't really like having to type "y" in the AA column to move it, the biggest problem with this is that it also moves the AA column to the other sheets as well, which at some point will be a huge problem.

This script also does not check for duplicates. There is a Google Sheet Data Validation feature that can do this, but for some reason, so far, when combined with scripting, it is spotty at best, and doesn't actually work 95% of the time.

Here is a copy of my Spreadsheet, it is set for anyone with link can edit. I do not think it is needed for this script, but feel free to see what I am working with and since it is a copy, I don't mind it breaking.

**Updated Link** (March 1st 2017)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u09DNmuotLTHMaF29sbPMrd_k-oRbRB7JGp4pWNgvfI/edit?usp=drivesdk

I am a dog groomer by trade so this scripting is not my cup of tea, and google sheet formulas are just a hobby along with gaming of course. :)

**Edit:** (March 1st 2017)

Below is my new script. I have added several new sheets and the script is working perfectly. I have also updated the above spreadsheet link to again include a new copy with full editing rights.

I do have a new question though. How do I go about undoing this? For instance, lets say I was to add a new sheet named "RemoveMember"?

```
function onEdit(event) {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 /*var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();*/
 // Nothing wrong with using event.source, It is easier to debug with the below code.
 var s = ss.getActiveSheet()
 var r = ss.getActiveRange()

 // The reason your previous code was checking for column AA was due to the following code r.getColumn() == 27 and r.getValue() == 'y'
 if(s.getName() == "AddMember" && r.getColumn() == 1) {
 var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("InputVPData");
 var tlastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()
 // targetMembers gets the previous members you have in the inputVpData 
 var targetMembers = targetSheet.getRange(8,1,tlastRow - 7,1).getValues()
 //RemoveDuplicates removes if any duplicates are found.
 var newMembers = removeDuplicates(r.getValues(),targetMembers)
 //check and see if you have any new entry before entering the data
 //important because getRange cannot have 0 as argument.
 if(newMembers.length != 0){
  targetSheet.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);

  var targetSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("InputSoulData");
  tlastRow = targetSheet2.getLastRow()

  targetSheet2.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);

  var targetSheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("InputDonatedData");
  tlastRow = targetSheet3.getLastRow()

  targetSheet3.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);

  var targetSheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("InputWonData");
  tlastRow = targetSheet4.getLastRow()

  targetSheet4.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);

  var targetSheet5 = ss.getSheetByName("InputCapturedData");
  tlastRow = targetSheet5.getLastRow()

  targetSheet5.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);

  var targetSheet6 = ss.getSheetByName("InputDefendedData");
  tlastRow = targetSheet6.getLastRow()

  targetSheet6.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);

  var targetSheet7 = ss.getSheetByName("InputLostData");
  tlastRow = targetSheet7.getLastRow()

  targetSheet7.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);
}

r.clear()

}

}


function removeDuplicates(newMembers, targetMembers){
 var uniqueMembers = []

 var counter =0
 for( var i=0; i< newMembers.length; i++)
{

var isunique = true;
for(var j=0 ; j < targetMembers.length; j++) {
  if(newMembers[i][0].trim() == targetMembers[j][0].trim())
  {

   isunique = false;
  }
}
  if(isunique){
  uniqueMembers[counter] = []
  uniqueMembers[counter][0] = newMembers[i][0]
  counter++
  }


 }
 return uniqueMembers
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  /*var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();*/
   // Nothing wrong with using event.source, It is easier to debug with the below code.
   var s = ss.getActiveSheet()
   var r = ss.getActiveRange()

  // The reason your previous code was checking for column AA was due to the following code r.getColumn() == 27 and r.getValue() == 'y'
  if(s.getName() == "AddMember" && r.getColumn() == 1) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("InputVPData");
    var tlastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()
    // targetMembers gets the previous members you have in the inputVpData 
    var targetMembers = targetSheet.getRange(8,1,tlastRow - 7,1).getValues()
    //RemoveDuplicates removes if any duplicates are found.
    var newMembers = removeDuplicates(r.getValues(),targetMembers)
    //check and see if you have any new entry before entering the data
    //important because getRange cannot have 0 as argument.
    if(newMembers.length != 0){
      targetSheet.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);

      var targetSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("InputSoulData");
      tlastRow = targetSheet2.getLastRow()

      targetSheet2.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);
    }

    r.clear()

  }

}


function removeDuplicates(newMembers, targetMembers){
  var uniqueMembers = []

  var counter =0
  for( var i=0; i< newMembers.length; i++)
  {

    var isunique = true;
    for(var j=0 ; j < targetMembers.length; j++) {
      if(newMembers[i][0].trim() == targetMembers[j][0].trim())
      {

       isunique = false;
      }
    }
      if(isunique){
      uniqueMembers[counter] = []
      uniqueMembers[counter][0] = newMembers[i][0]
      counter++
      }


  }
  return uniqueMembers
}
```

You were on the right track, just added a function called remove Duplicates to check for duplicates before entering the value in those two sheets. However note, I only check for duplicates with the data from InputVPData. You can do the same for InputSoulData sheet if you like.

**Edit:** How to look for duplicates in the second sheet. The trick lies in these code:

```
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("InputVPData");
        var tlastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()
        // targetMembers gets the previous members you have in the inputVpData 
        var targetMembers = targetSheet.getRange(8,1,tlastRow - 7,1).getValues()
        //RemoveDuplicates removes if any duplicates are found.
        var newMembers = removeDuplicates(r.getValues(),targetMembers)
```

what this code does is gets the sheet called "InputVPData" and then figure out the lastrow which has data. Then gets the all the values in column one from row 8 till lastrow - 7 by using this:

```
 var targetMembers = targetSheet.getRange(8,1,tlastRow - 7,1).getValues()
 getRange(StartRow,StartColumn,NoofRows,noOfColumns)=> Get the range
 getValues() => Get the value of said range
```

Similarly, we get the value of entered data using r.getValues() and pass it to this function

```
removeDuplicates(r.getValues(),targetMembers)
```

which removes duplicates from the entered data (r.getValues) and returns it to the variable newMembers, like so

```
 var newMembers = removeDuplicates(r.getValues(),targetMembers)
```

this newMember is then added to your targetSheet using the setValues function like so:

```
targetSheet.getRange(tlastRow + 1, 1,newMembers.length, 1).setValues(newMembers);
```

All you need to do is duplicate the above code to get a new set of newMembers2 after using the removeduplicates function on r.getValues and targetSheet2 members. 
Once you get that list once again use setValues to set values in the new sheet from the variable newMembers2.

Comment: Bah, it won't let me up tick your response. I know nothing about scripting. I borrowed someone elses code and gradually got a little something out of it.. how would i also check for duplicates in the InputSoulData sheet... Lol.. sorry, it isn't so clear for me.. if i had more time tonight, i would stare at until it made sense... Lol

Comment: I will edit the answer to point you in the right direction, but I will still let you figure it out. Better to stumble than to have never fallen.

Comment: edited the answer so you can figure out how to modify your code. PS: IF you keep your googleSheet link share on, I will give you inputs as you modify your code :)

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to try out your script. I suddenly had to change gears and focus entirely on work. I have looked through your notes and was planning on making the additions you were talking about, however, when I used the code script you provided, it ended up doing exactly what I needed it to. No changes needed. Thank you so much for your help. I updated the original post to include a new copy of my current spreadsheet with full rights to edit. It works wonderfully. I wish I had enough reputation to up vote you. Someone else who can should!

Comment: I have added more sheets for inputting Data. I have modified your script to reflect these changes and everything works absolutely perfectly. However, 
I do have a new question though. How do I go about undoing this? For instance, lets say I was to add a new sheet named "RemoveMember"?

Comment: Could you make a new question/thread with minimal executable code and a clear question of what you are trying to achieve? This way you get more eyes on your question. Thanks!

Comment: But in short, modify the removeduplicates function so that whenever you have a match you can remove the item out using splice function

Comment: I created a new thread like you recommend. But Not sure what you mean by minimal executable code.  I additionally thought of an issue with my new question found here and corrected it in the new thread. I looked at attempting to edit the script myself but my mind circled back to trying to use sheet formula's to do everything, but the idea I came up with trying seemed so convoluted compared to how nice and neat things are in your script I felt it was worth posting the new thread anyway and I ended with trying it myself honestly being outside my ability via scripting.